# <link rel="prefetch"> does not reuse the fetched resource in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I am currently trying to prefetch some images in a single page application written in AngularJS. To reuse them after routing to another state.

I want to do this by injecting some prefetch links during runtime.
While this works fine in chrome and IE11, it does not use the fetched resource in Firefox.

```
app.run(($document) => {
    const head = $document.find('head');
    const prefetchImage = $document[0].createElement('link');
    prefetchImage.rel = 'prefetch';
    prefetchImage.href = url;
    head.append(prefetchImage);
});
```

```html
<img src="url" />
```

I would expect the application to reuse the prefetched image, but it seems like in Firefox the Application just requests it twice.

Anyone knows why this might be the case?

Comment: Do your images have a `Cache-Control` header?

Comment: Yes, 

Cache-Control: max-age=1800

Comment: Found my problem. Did not notice that `pragma: no-cache` was set on my images. Apparently Chrome and Firefox do not care about that header when a resource is prefetched, but firefox does.